# Bukkit Register Commands in Runtime

Tags: java, minecraft, bukkit

I am trying to register a bukkit Command on the other Command.

So I want to make "/command1" to register "/command2" so command 2 only can execute after I executed command 1.

I tried for like 10 hours by now to do that, at the moment I am able to register a command without making it into the plugin.yml and that works, just the second command does not get registered.

Main class:

```
import lombok.Getter;
import org.bukkit.Bukkit;
import org.bukkit.command.CommandMap;
import org.bukkit.plugin.SimplePluginManager;
import org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPlugin;

import java.lang.reflect.Field;

public class Main extends JavaPlugin {

@Getter
CommandMap commandMap;
@Override
public void onEnable() {
    loadCommandMap();
    this.commandMap.register("command1", new FirstCommand(this));
}


private void loadCommandMap() {
    try {
        if (Bukkit.getPluginManager() instanceof SimplePluginManager) {
            Field f = SimplePluginManager.class.getDeclaredField("commandMap");
            f.setAccessible(true);
            this.commandMap = (CommandMap) f.get(Bukkit.getPluginManager());
        }
    } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SecurityException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

FirstCommand:

```
import org.bukkit.command.Command;
import org.bukkit.command.CommandSender;

public class FirstCommand extends Command {
private Main plugin;

public FirstCommand(Main plugin) {
    super("command1");
    this.plugin = plugin;
}

@Override
public boolean execute(CommandSender sender, String commandLabel, String[] args) {
    plugin.getCommandMap().register("command2", new SecondCommand());
    sender.sendMessage("Command 1.");
    return true;
}
}
```

Second Command:

```
import org.bukkit.command.Command;
import org.bukkit.command.CommandSender;

public class SecondCommand extends Command {
public SecondCommand() {
    super("command2");
}

@Override
public boolean execute(CommandSender sender, String commandLabel, String[] args) {
    sender.sendMessage("Command 2");
    return true;
}
}
```

I really hope someone knows why the first command gets registered but the second one does not.

Comment: Have you tried printing the `commandmap` after you've registered `SecondCommand`?

Comment: yes i tried that. but the output said that it was registed so in the map it was registed

Comment: Are you sure that the command map is the same instance? If you register secondcommand at `onEnable` does it work? If you deregister `FirstCommand` later does it disappear? If it doesn't then it might be the case Bukkit makes a copy of the command map.

Comment: i just found out a thing that make absolutly no sens to me. turns out, the commands work, but only if i enter them in console. if i enter them ingame they dont work. btw. yea if u unregister FirstCommand it disapears.

Answer (score 1):

The CraftServer has a method called syncCommands(), which synchronizes the commands in the CommandMap with the players and the console.

You can call it using:

```
((CraftServer) server).syncCommands();
```

The reason why the first command is available  is because spigot executes syncCommands() after all plugins are enabled.
For me it solved the problem and I hope it does it for you aswell!

Answer (score -1):

You could try to not *register* them at runtime, but *enable* them at runtime.

You can use global, static variables (for example in the main class of your app), e.g.

```
// in your class "Main"
public static boolean isCommand2Enabled = false;
```

and when `command1` is called, you set it to true

```
Main.isCommand2Enabled = true;
```

Your command2 must now only check whether it has already been activated and can be executed:

```
if(!Main.isCommand2Enabled) {
   // I am not activated yet and must return
   return false;
}
```

But I am not quite sure if you might try to define the name of command2 first when command1 is executed (variable command name). You should then maybe use a fixed command and only make the corresponding argument variable.

Comment: Well i woud kind of agree with that except in the case where i wannt to use it later i need to register them later. because i am trying to load the Plugin in runtime when i Use it, to explain the whole project woud probalby go way over the character limit. But basicly i have a framework that loads commands with annotations and that works now completly, except the registering in runtime. and because this is a framework i cant just "enable" them like you sugested. i need my framework to beeing able to load them und unload them. the unloading part i managed to do, but i struggle with the loading.